# Proposal for "error" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I propose to add tag "error" (synonym "mistake") for questions like [Category theory - where is my error?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576382/category-theory-where-is-my-error)

Comment: We also already have a very similar tag [tag:fake-proofs].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a meta tag, it is about the type of question and not about the topic of the question. There are no experts in the tag of [error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error), and there is no reason to use it as a favorite tag or to search for questions with that specific tag.

Tags work best if they are about the topic of the question, if they are useful to select questions fitting to your expertise, or if they can be used to find questions. If a tag is not useful in this way, it is often a bad idea to use it at all.

Comment: I think there are quite a few experts on the topic of errors. :-) But not in a helpful way!

Comment: There are certainly experts in the topic of error-detection, in the sense of users who are (1) expert in the content tags of a question, and (2) qualitatively more willing than other users to pore over the question, line by line, to find the actual point where a problem occurs.  Conversely, there are expers who have no interest in questions that require close parsing of OP-mathematics.  The correction of the second paragraph is tags "work... if they are useful to select questions an expert is *interested in answering*".  So what you write seems rather an argument in favor of such metatags.